# What is the best way to execute intensive javascript without blocking?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, three.js, webgl

So, I'm loading a 3d model using webgl, and have some code to perform some operations on it before displaying it.

The problem is that this takes on the order of seconds and completely blocks the user from doing anything in the meantime. It's bad enough that you can't even scroll during this period. I've heard there's no such thing as multithreading in javascript, but I need someway for it not to block the main thread.

I even tried a setup where I load it in an iframe and using *window.postMessage* and a *message* event listener, but it seems the frame's domain uses the same thread for its javascript as well so that didn't work. Anyone else have a solution for dealing with CPU intensive code so that the user isn't blocked from doing anything?

Comment: WebWorkers .........

Comment: I've never tried this before, but how about opening a pop under window in which the rendering takes place. Once the load event fires pluck the DOM node from the window and insert it into your page? I'd post an answer but I need to do some playing around first.

Comment: Is the _loading_ of the model the primary problem you are facing -- and not the callback? If so, try `CTMLoader` which can optionally use WebWorkers. http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_ctm.html.

Answer (score 4):

There really isn't an easy answer at least at the moment

1. WebWorkers

   Web worker run JavaScript in another thread. Unfortunately they are extremely limited it what they are allowed to do. Generally all you can do is pass messages back and forth. A WebWorker can not touch the DOM, it can not do WebGL or make Canvas (yet). All you can really do currently is networking and passing strings and/or typed arrays to and from a WebWorker.

   If the thing you are doing that takes lots of time can be passed back to the main thread in a JSON string and/or typed arrays this might work for you.
2. A state machine

   A common way to handle this in JavaScript is to make your loader do things over several states so that you can call it something like this

   ```
   function doALittleMoreWork() {
      ...
      if (theresStillMoreWorkToDo) {
        setTimeout(doALittleMoreWork, 16);
      } 
   }
   ```

   Or something along those lines. `doALittleMoreWork` does a portion of the work and then remembers enough state so when called again it can continue where it left off. This is how the [O3D loader worked](https://code.google.com/p/o3d/source/browse/trunk/samples/o3djs/serialization.js).
3. You could try to use [ES6 generators](http://davidwalsh.name/es6-generators).

   Generators effectively let you create a state machine super easy. Browsers don't yet support ES6 but there are libraries that let you use this feature now like for example [Google Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler)

   In fact if you write a simple generator like

   ```
   function *foo() {
       console.log("do first thing");
       yield 1;
       console.log("do 2nd thing");
       yield 2;
       console.log("do 3rd thing");
       yield 3;
       console.log("do 4th thing");
       yield 4;
       console.log("do 5th thing");
       yield 5;
   }
   ```

   and you run it through traceur [you'll see how it turns it into a state machine for you](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html#%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20*foo()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22do%20first%20thing%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22do%202nd%20thing%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%202%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22do%203rd%20thing%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%203%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22do%204th%20thing%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%204%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22do%205th%20thing%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%205%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A) like #2 above.

Answer (score 1):

[Web workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) is definitely what you need

Comment: So it says web workers can't manipulate the DOM. Can they add event listeners to DOM elements or is that also no allowed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with webgl very much, but I guess you can process operations with it directly in worker, while page working with usual code. Maybe this link will be helpful: http://greenido.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/web-workers-and-big-data-a-real-world-example/